# Use gitlab Repo in Docker Hub

Tags: docker, gitlab

Does anyone know how to use a gitlab repo in an automated build from docker? I know you can bind a github or bitbucket repo. Is there a easy way for gitlab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not believe that is a feature. You will probably have to use your own CI to build and push an image. Alternatively, gitlab can mirror to a github repo that you use only to trigger automated builds.

According to [This issue](https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/334), gitlab integration is in progress.

Comment: Also in that issue, they say maybe gitlab's own build system may be able to push to docker hub.